# Need to get email notification if column in Google Spreadsheet is changed

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script that triggers a notification whenever a value is changed in a specific column of a Google Spreadsheet.  Ideally, I would like to trigger notifications to other people, each based on changes to specific columns.

I have a test spreadsheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V4X1FNtYKbXhha84MzeU8kI57ck246WfvSluHlsP1eo/edit?usp=sharing

And have found a script for a custom notification elsewhere in the answers on SO.  I took that and tweaked it until I got this:

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var column = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var colLetter = columnToLetter(column);
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "email@domain.org";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('G')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('F'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Update to Notification TEST Sheet';
  var body = 'Sheet ' +sheet.getName() + ' has been updated.   Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + '  View the changes in row ' + row + ', column ' +colLetter+ '.';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
function columnToLetter(column) {
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

function letterToColumn(letter)
{
  var column = 0, length = letter.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
  }
  return column;
};
```

Once you change the receipient email, the script runs, but sends a notification for any change in any cell, not for cells with a specific column.

Can anyone help me get it to do what I am looking for?
TIA!

Comment: If this code works, then it seems like you just need to check if the row and column are the desired ones.  If they are, then send the email, if not, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your trigger event is, `onEdit(e)`

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();

  if(column == `your expected column number`)
  {
   // call your send notification function
   sendNotification();
  }
}
```

You can read about triggers more. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)